# Looking for an MPI routine

Tags: c, mpi, subroutine

So just today I started messing around with the MPI library in C and I've tried it out some and have now found myself in a situation where I need the following:

A routine that'll send a message to a random process in a blocking receive while leaving the others still blocked.

Does such a routine exist? If not, how can something like this be accomplished?

Answer (score 0):

No, such routine does not exist. However, you can easily build one using the available routines in the MPI standard. For example if you want a routine that sends to a random process which is not the current one you can write the following:

```
int MPI_SendRand(void *data, unsigned size, int tag, MPI_Comm comm, MPI_Status *status) {
  // one process sends
  int comm_size, my_rank, dest;
  MPI_Comm_rank(comm, &my_rank);
  MPI_Comm_size(comm, &comm_size);
  // random number between [0, comm_size) excluding my_rank
  while ((dst = ((float)rand())/RAND_MAX*comm_size)) == my_rank) ;
  return MPI_Send(data, size, dst, tag, comm, status);
}
```

can be used as follows:

```
if (rank == master) {
  MPI_SendRand(some_data, sime_size, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
} else {
  // the rest waits
  MPI_Recv(some_buff, some_size, MPI_SOURCE_ANY, MPI_TAG_ANY, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
  // do work...
}
```